# Is there any place I can ride an America’s Cup class hydrofoil catamaran (AC75 type?)

Tags: where-on-earth, sailing

Where, if anywhere, can I get a ride an America’s Cup class hydrofoil catamaran (AC75 type?)

Edit: Oops, yes I meant the AC50 type.

Comment: Does it need to be that type exactly, or would any sailing vessel work (i.e.  a Moth or a Hobie)?

Comment: @CGCampbell Are you seriously suggesting a 5m yacht would be be suitable when the OP is asking about a 23m yacht?  They're not even in the same ocean let alone league. :D (and also the AC75 is a monohull)

Comment: No. However, no one that is not part of the community, or very wealthy, is going to "get a ride on one". They might make it as crew, but on a day trip, it's simply not an option. If what he wants, however, is simply to ride a hydrofoil-sailboat, he might not be aware that there are smaller craft available where it might be possible.

Comment: There's a former racing boat that does daysails with crew out of San Francisco.  I'm pretty confident it's not a foiling class, but it is a famous boat that won a few races.  I'm sorry that I can't remember the name, and a quick google search didn't reveal it.  I'm 100% sure I'm remembering this right, though, so more googling should reveal it.

Answer (score 2):

Given what [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC75) page says about AC75 class yachts:

> The AC75 (America's Cup 75 class) is a 75-ft monohull sailboat class, governing the construction and operation of the yachts to be used in the 2021 America's Cup. Conceptual graphics were proposed by the defender on 20 November 2017, and the full Class Rule rule was published on 29 March 2018

I doubt that any yachts have yet been built that meet that spec.

Now you may be able to find [AC50 yachts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC50) (previous AC generation) that give rides but I couldn't find any with a quick google.

Finally I think you also may be confusing types.  The AC50 is a catamaran, while the AC75 is (going to be) a monohull.